# Failed to import authentication backend after changing the airflow.cfg

Tags: flask, airflow

After changing the `airflow.cfg`, I simply changed the authenticate to True like this:

```
[webserver]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
```

when I run command `airflow webserver`, there was an Error as below:

```
  File "/home/airflow/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/password_auth.py", line 33, in <module>
    from flask_bcrypt import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_bcrypt'

...

File "/home/airflow/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 73, in load_login
    raise AirflowException("Failed to import authentication backend")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Failed to import authentication backend
```

Just added the content in airflow.cfg file.

```
[webserver]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved it .

```
pip install flask-bcrypt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip3 install flask-bcrypt --user
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

The official way to fix this error is by installing the `password` subpackage, which will pull in the needed dependencies for password authentication.

```
pip install 'apache-airflow[password]'
```

A list of available subpackages is available [in the airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/installation.html#extra-packages).